# How to post data edit and resubmit the data in python django using Javascript Fetch Function?

Tags: javascript, python, django

In my project, the user enters their post (or comments) in the post field and if he/she wants their re-edit the post, click the edit button and data will present in the Textarea field (using javascript). In Textarea, the user wants to reedit the data and submit it.
In My doubt is, when I click the edit button the textarea will present and data also editable but it will not post in the database while I am using the fetch function( my target is without refresh the entire page the data will post using javascript fetch function)and also data-id not passing to the javascript function. Kindly help in this regard.

**index.html**

````
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">        
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                            <a href="{% url 'profile' datas.id %}">{{datas.user_id|capfirst}}</a></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-6 text-right" > 
                        {% if request.user.id == datas.user_id_id %}
                            <!--<button id="edit" value="{{datas.post}}" onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button> -->
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" value="{{datas.post}}" onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div id="msg">
                        <hr>
                        {{datas.post}}
                        <hr>
                </div>  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div> 
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">{{datas.post_date}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
{% endfor %}

**inbox.js**
function edit(id)
{   
    //var body = event.value;
    var notes = id.value;
    var one = id.closest(".card-body");

    one.querySelector("#msg").innerHTML = '<form id="wel" ><div class="form-group" >'+
            '<textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="3">'+notes+'</textarea>'+
        '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" /></div></form>'; 
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelector('#wel').onsubmit = out;
  // By default, load the inbox
  
});
     
}

function out(id){
     const data= document.querySelector('#body').value;
     fetch(`/network/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            post: data
        })
    }).then();
}```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnrIh.jpg
````

Comment: Did you try using ajax?